# inserting HTML POST form field data into PHPmailer email body

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer

I have tried every hint I have found across the web and here but what I cannot achieve is for the sent email to contain the form data in the html formatted message.  The mailing function is working and I get the email properly.

The form is basically:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" name="Work Record" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="first_name" id="staff_name2" placeholder="First" required />

<input type="text" name="last_name" id="staff_name" placeholder="Last" required />

<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="head-l" id="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()">
```

And using the latest phpmailer from google the action script is as follows.  I have the emailing function working through gmail, I am just not sure what to put where to pull the data from the form and put it into the email body.  The code that is pasted in the body now is that we used to use before switching to phpmailer.  Thank you!

```
<?php
require '/home/newnplhftp/nplh.us/smtp/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxx';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

$mail->From = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$mail->FromName = 'NPLH';
$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');               // Name is optional

$mail->AddCC('');
$mail->AddBCC('');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$mail->Body = '
<html>
<h2><b>$first_name $last_name, $license_type</b></h2>
</html>';

$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Thank you, your message has been sent!';

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set;

```
$mail->Body = '
<html>
<h2><b>$first_name $last_name, $license_type</b></h2>
</html>';
```

to

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$license_type = $_POST['license_type'];

    $mail->Body = "
    <html>
    <h2><b>".$first_name." ".$last_name.", ".$license_type."</b></h2>
    </html>";
```

Comment: @VIDesignz maverabil was using double quotes before you modified your answer ;-)

Comment: I hope  both solution fix your problem:)

Comment: Finally...   I had to use ".$first_name." format to pull the form field in; just the plain $first_name alone did not work and just displayed that in text!  Thanks guys... I'm sure I'll be back soon!!

Comment: @JesseBarnes That isn't the case if the string has double quotes. Such as "Hi there $first_name" Concatenating only makes more work for yourself really.

Comment: @VIDesignz - that makes sense... Thanks for clarifying that for me!

Answer (score 1):

The variables you are trying to send need to be captured from the the form first. This would happen on `test.php` since this is where you are posting the values to.

So you would do this

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$license_type = $_POST['license_type'];
```

Then you can use them inside the mail body.

```
$mail->Body = "<html><h2><b>$first_name $last_name, $license_type</b></h2></html>";
```

Though I would highly suggest validating that data in some way first.

Comment: I read over that in one other post but (and don't laugh too hard) where exactly do I put that bit of code?  The users need a password to access the form, so i am not too worried about the validation at this point, but I will add that once I have this working great.

Comment: Even if the form itself is only available to logged in users does not at all protect the page that the form gets posted to. A user can simply use curl to post to the unprotected page (test.php) without using 'your' form.

Comment: You must use double quotes if you want variables to be interpreted.

Comment: @LucM Good catch, didn't quite look at that since that was not the crux of the question, but thank you.

Comment: @VIDesignz - on the CURL note...  the test.php is located in the home directory above the site URL... isn't that the safest place for it?

Comment: @JesseBarnes There is not really a safe place regarding curl, as it acts pretty much just like a browser would. There is no way to differentiate a browser request from a curl request.